# Bash Shell - Change text inside tag AND remove all content inside tag

Tags: html, bash, sed

I need to remove/change some content from an html file

From this one i need to remove everything , from the beggining of the div tag till the end of /div

```html
<div id="footer" role="contentinfo">
    <section class="footer-body">
        <p>Document generated by Confluence on 2017/03/27 09:41</p>
            <div id="footer-logo">
                <a href="http://www.atlassian.com/">Atlassian</a></div>
    </section>
            </div>
```

And here i need to change the Author and Editor names

```html
Created by <span class='author'>John Smith</span>, last modified by <span class='editor'> John Smith</span> on 2017/03/24
```

I know i need to use sed , but i have no idea how to create said expressions

Comment: In first sample input you have two nested div tags. Which one do you need to delete? How deep can nesting get? Is two nested div tags the maximum? The indendation is misleading on this point. What forces you to use sed? Several comments will recommend using at least awk, if not an appropriate XML/HTML parser. You might also find comments asking for the things you tried, missing the impression that you have done some sed manual reading, some simple experiments. There is some help available on how to ask a good question.

Comment: E.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the 1st challenge please be more specific.

This is the sed script for the 2nd challenge:

```
source="Created by <span class='author'>John Smith</span>, last modified by <span class='editor'> John Smith</span> on 2017/03/24"
author="new author"
editor="new editor"
result=`echo "$source" | sed "s/\(.*author'>\).*\(<\/span>,.*editor'>\).*\(<\/span.*\)/\1$author\2$editor\3/"`

echo $result
```